# What is the name of the clip on the Raspberry Pi display connector?

Tags: connector, raspberry-pi

I bought a Raspberry Pi Display v1.1 but the clip where panel 1 connects is missing (a brown clip, on a white connector). What is the name and size of this clip / connector?

See here [Someone with the clip](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93003/where-to-buy-the-raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display-board-separately)

Missing clip:

[image: Missing clip and the connector of interest]

Comment: You might be able to get the board-only as a "spares or repair" item from somewhere like eBay, making sure that the one you're buying has an intact connector, which you (or someone else) can transfer to your board. Or maybe you're the person who got the item shown as "This listing sold on Mon, 11 Mar at 10:51 AM."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of 0.5mm pitch bottom-contact connectors that will fit this footprint, but you'd have to match the actual manufacturer (or a clone) pretty closely to get the clip to fit. I don't share Davide's pessimism on the swapping the clip out. I would suggest going through his list and seeing if any photos seem to match (I did not do that).

From a quick look, it appears to be very close to [this](https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/molex/0527460671/2074148) Molex part
0527460671 (image from Digikey linked):
[image]

I would suggest

1. go through Davide's list and see if there are any closer matches.
2. buy a few (shipping charges will dominate anyway) and try to get the clip out
   and put it in the existing connector. Chances are it was designed to snap in
   since they're obviously different parts assembled later. You may have to cut the white plastic since the snap appears to be [chamfered](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2401301209_MOLEX-0527460671_C5464715.pdf?_gl=1*1voe3hf*_ga*MTU3OTE3NjkxLjE2OTIyMzg3MjU.*_ga_98M84MKSZH*MTcxMDE3MTc0NC4yNi4xLjE3MTAxNzMxMDYuNjAuMC4w) for entrance only (one-time assembly assumed).
3. If you fail, quit while you still have one or two left and attempt desoldering
   and replacing the part using hot air or whatever fine SMT techniques you have
   available to you (or take it to some mobile phone repair technician who should be able to do that with their eyes closed).

[image]

Comment: Shipping charges will dominate only if this is the only thing you order. If you are ordering from DigiKey, just add like 50$ worth of other things to your order (not useless junk, but actual tools that you need) and you get free shipping.

Comment: @tpimh Good point. I maintain lists of things to add on to regular suppliers' orders the next time I need something relatively urgently. In this case, that other stuff would dominate the order cost.

Answer (score 8):

That is a right-angle FFC socket with a 0.5 mm pitch and bottom contacts. It appears to be broken: the actuator is missing.

Here is a [List of possible replacements](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets&&fl=000000000000000000000000001120-f-%7C6%7C.5) (from my Identiconn site).

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [Amphenol ICC (FCI)](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/0-50mm-ffc-fpc-connectors.html) - [Aorora F300 301](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/flex/ffc_fpc_050mm_f300_f301.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/w70dm1mj)
- [Amphenol ICC (FCI)](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/0-50mm-ffc-fpc-connectors.html) - [Aorora F305](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/flex/ffc_fpc_050mm_f305.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/rf130b8t)
- [Amphenol ICC (FCI)](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/0-50mm-ffc-fpc-connectors.html) - [Aorora F308](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/flex/ffc_fpc_050mm_f308.pdf) (pdf)
- GCT - FFC2B35 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/1hfmm0h9)
- [Hirose Electric](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/series/FH12) - [FH12 0.5 mm](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FH12&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31648_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/vq330z5z)
- Hirose Electric - [FH19](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Hirose%20PDFs/FH19_19S_Series.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/cmzcbwzh)
- Hirose Electric - [FH19SC](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Hirose%20PDFs/FH19C_FH19SC_Series.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/7qdw15rd)
- Hirose Electric - [FH33 0.5 mm](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FH33&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49357_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/1dffzzf0)
- Hirose Electric - [FH33J 0.5 mm](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FH33&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49357_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/574h85zf)
- Hirose Electric - [FH52 0.5 mm](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=CL0580-3303-8-99&productname=FH52-50S-0.5SH(99)&series=FH52&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=en_FH52_CAT) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/q7rfdzd3)
- [Hirose Electric](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/series/TF31) - [TF31](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=TF31&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D51105_en) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/9d815w2w)
- [JAE](https://www.jae.com/en/connectors/series/detail/id=64321&type_code=T1030) - [FA5](https://www.jae.com/direct/topics/topics_file_download/topics_id=64321&ext_no=08&_lang=en&v=2021090616233354948909) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/32cppt8z)
- Kyocera AVX - 6239 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/h9hfdwq0)
- [Kyocera AVX](https://ele.kyocera.com/en/product/connector/fpcffc_connectors/6240) - [6240](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/connector/6240.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/frdpvrn9)
- [Kyocera AVX](https://ele.kyocera.com/en/product/connector/fpcffc_connectors/6288) - [6288](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/connector/6288.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/bn10d0fw)
- Kyocera AVX - 6299 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/fbzmwjn9)
- [Kyocera AVX](https://ele.kyocera.com/en/product/connector/fpcffc_connectors/6809/) - [6809](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/connector/6809.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/tdq3rj42)
- [Kyocera AVX](https://ele.kyocera.com/en/product/connector/fpcffc_connectors/6811/) - [6811](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/connector/6811.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/n3p78bct)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/easyon_ffc_fpc_connectors) - [Easy-on 51296 104234 104267 502244 505110 505278](https://www.molex.com/molex/search/literatureSearch?orderNumber=987652-0021) (pdf) - [molex](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/512960894_sd.pdf)
- [W�rth Elektronik](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/FPC_0_5_SMT_ZIF_VERTICAL_6873XX124422) - [WR-FPC 6871 Front](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Wurth%20Electronics%20PDFs/WR-FPC_FFC_Flyer.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/b02ftfq5)

It may be a [slider FFC socket](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ffc_fpc_slider_sockets&&fl=000000000000000000000000001120-f-%7C6%7C.5):

- MANUF. - SERIES
- Adam Tech - PCA 0.5mm - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/prfmb1mp)
- [Amphenol ICC (FCI)](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/0-50mm-ffc-fpc-connectors.html) - [Aorora F31L](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/flex/ffc_fpc_050mm_f31l.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/bbm3z51b)
- [Amphenol ICC (FCI)](https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/0-50mm-ffc-fpc-connectors.html) - [Aorora F32R](https://cdn.amphenol-cs.com/media/wysiwyg/files/documentation/datasheet/flex/ffc_fpc_050mm_f32r_f32q.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/v8zb4cqr)
- Amphenol ICC (FCI) - SFV-R - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/5j2tqmdj)
- Amphenol ICC (FCI) - SFVL - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/mf0qtfmv)
- Cvilux USA - CF20 CF25 CF31 CF34 CF35 CF50 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/mwh8wtm0)
- GCT - FFC2A32 FFC2A33 FFC2B16 FFC2B17 FFC2B21 FFC2B22 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/tvd05vp7)
- JAE - IL-FPR - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/m75250rt)
- [JST](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=79) - [FLZ](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eFLZ.pdf?62b087e960ced) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/7vmwwv7j)
- [Kyocera AVX](https://ele.kyocera.com/en/product/connector/fpcffc_connectors/6210) - [6210](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/connector/6210.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/wj0fpd28)
- [Kyocera AVX](https://ele.kyocera.com/en/product/connector/fpcffc_connectors/6260) - [6260](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/connector/6260.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/5h8b49jw)
- [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/easyon_ffc_fpc_connectors) - [Easy-on 52746 52437 52132](https://www.molex.com/molex/search/literatureSearch?orderNumber=987652-0021) (pdf)
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/pcb-connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/ffc-fpc-ribbon-connectors/fpc-connectors.html?tab=pgp-story) - 1-1734 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/jqqdjw32)
- [W�rth Elektronik](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/FPC_0_5_SMT_ZIF_VERTICAL_6873XX124422) - [WR-FPC 6871 Slide](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Wurth%20Electronics%20PDFs/WR-FPC_FFC_Flyer.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.ee/short/v953qm93)

Comment: If I would buy a replacement online, could I just swap out the actuator?

Comment: No. The actuator would break in the process. You need to replace the entire socket.

Comment: Shame, thanks for the help.

Comment: Follow @Spehro Pefhany 's excellent advice.

Comment: You can cut the connector open without damaging the clip, the the clip should just click into the old connector given that the old connector was not damaged.